# Django Class Based View Generic To Accept List

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using class based views to return a list based upon a GET request.  My class is inheriting from generics.ListAPIView.  The issue that I'm having is that generics.ListAPIView expects a queryset object.  Instead of a queryset object, I would like to use a row or dictionary object.  How can I configure the generics.ListAPIView to accept a list or dictionary instead of a queryset or RAWqueryset object?

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

Comment: "*expects a queryset object. Instead of a queryset object*"?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i'm not following....i would like to pass a list or dictionary, which I'm generating from connection.cursor.execute.fetchall(), to my class which is inheriting from generics.ListAPIView.

Comment: @PyNoob What are you trying to achieve here? What you mean by this, **expects a queryset object. Instead of a queryset object**?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge instead of using the ORM to complete a query across tables, I would like to complete a raw query.  Executing a raw query on the model object would result in a queryset object and therefore can be accepted by the generics.ListAPIView.  However, when executing a raw query on the object, you only have that objects (tables) columns available. So, i abstracted to a higher level and executed a raw query on the connection engine, which has access to all tables so i can do a normal select and join across tables.  However, the results object from ...cursor.fetchall() returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it would be easier to write your own method, like [here](https://gitlab.begel.fr/guillaume/lecturaddicts_server/blob/63bd51da2858f3f41b9bd3cc081492e7f1036f47/members/views/proposed_theme.py#L76).

With the result of `cursor.fetchall()`, you can't paginate efficiently/filter/whatever anyway...